Evaluate and Save a DNN Linear Combined Classifier Model in Tensorflow
I'm using tensorflow estimator for my model and it works for training and evaluation part (Code snippet given below). While the accuracy being displayed from the results are 93%, the precision and recall are both 0 which should not be possible. This is the case for both the train results and test results.
I want to get the predictions from the model and calculate the performance metrics myself. Apart from this, I also want to save the trained model (Any kind of format works with me). Below is a small part of the code I'm using. labeled_features is the main dataset being used for them model and train_spec and eval_spec are just parts of the main dataset.
Please assume that the variables such as hidden_units and dropout_rate are having values relevant to the model/dataset which are working fine since it would be too big of a post if give the sample code for every variable.
import tensorflow as tf

wide_columns = []

wide_columns += [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
    key = 'user_id', hash_bucket_size = 1000, dtype = tf.dtypes.int64)] 

wide_columns += [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
    key = 'product_id', hash_bucket_size = 100, dtype = tf.dtypes.int64)] 

wide_columns += [tf.feature_column.crossed_column(
    ['user_id', 'product_id'], hash_bucket_size = 1000)]

deep_columns = []

cat_keys = {}
for col in cat_features:
    cat_keys[col] = (labeled_features.selectExpr('{0} as key'.format(col)).distinct().orderBy('key')
                     .groupBy().agg(f.collect_list('key').alias('keys')).collect()[0]['keys'])

# categorical features
for col in cat_features:
    if col not in ['user_id', 'product_id']:
        col_def = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(
            key=col, num_buckets=np.max(cat_keys[col]) + 1)
        deep_columns += [tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
            col_def, dimension=int(np.max(cat_keys[col]) ** 0.25))]

# continuous features
for col in num_features:
    deep_columns += [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(col)]


model = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
    linear_feature_columns = wide_columns,
    linear_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Ftrl(),
    dnn_feature_columns = deep_columns,
    dnn_hidden_units = hidden_units,
    dnn_dropout = dropout_rate,
    dnn_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adagrad()
)

train_results = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model, train_spec, eval_spec)

batch_size = 128
steps = int(test.count() / batch_size)
test_results = model.evaluate(test_spec, steps = steps)

For getting the predictions from the model, I have tried the following code which keeps running endlessly until I stop the execution myself.
predictions = model.predict(get_input_fn(test))
predictions_df = spark.createDataFrame(predictions)

For saving the model, I have tried several syntaxes - none of which have worked. Below are two attempts (that I noticed are most commonly used) I have made along with the respective error I got.
Attempt 1:
model_path = "path/to/model"

feature_columns = wide_columns + deep_columns
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))

export_path = model.export_saved_model(model_path, serving_input_fn)


ValueError: feature_columns contain different parse_spec for key user_id. Given VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string) and VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)

Attempt 2:
model_path = "path/to/model"
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model = model)
checkpoint.save(model_path)
tf.saved_model.save(model, model_path)


ValueError: Checkpoint was expecting model to be a trackable object (an object derived from Trackable), got <tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.estimator.Estimator object at 0x7f2571ff5a20>. If you believe this object should be trackable (i.e. it is part of the TensorFlow Python API and manages state), please open an issue.


Your issue has 3 parts: 1- performance metrics (Precision/Recall being 0) 2- Using model.predict directly can be inefficient when working with large datasets. We'll use a batched approach to handle this efficiently
3- tf.estimator models are not compatible with tf.saved_model.save as they use a different saving mechanism. We'll use the appropriate method to export your model
To fix #1: make sure labels are in the correct format and calculating metrics after predictions.
To fix #2:
 import pandas as pd
 def predict_with_batches(model, input_fn):
    results = []
    for pred in model.predict(input_fn):
        results.append(pred)
    return pd.DataFrame(results)

def test_input_fn():
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_features).batch(128)

predictions_df = predict_with_batches(model, test_input_fn)

To fix way to save the model
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(wide_columns + deep_columns)
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
model_path = "path/to/saved_model"
export_path = model.export_saved_model(model_path, serving_input_fn)
print(f"Model saved to: {export_path}")


Hi Ali. Thanks a lot for your response. I tried out the suggested fix for #2. I'm assuming that 'test_features' variable is just wide_columns + deep_columns. Using that code, I'm getting the error - "Expected values test_features to be a dense tensor with shape [27, 3], but got shape [27]."
As for the fix for #3, I have already tried it out - as mentioned in my attempt #1 - and I get the same error as mentioned in my post.
